# How to read tree from xml C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have following class used to keep a tree.

```
public class TreeNode
{
    private Dictionary<string, DataInfo> node;
    private List<TreeNode> children = new List<TreeNode>();
    ...
    ...
}
```

The DataInfo is like:

```
public class DataInfo
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a method in this class to save this tree nodes into XML. The XML looks like:

```
<Tree>
  <Node>
    <Item Type="System.String">
      <Property>Name</Property>
      <Value>v1</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item Type="System.Int32">
      <Property>i</Property>
      <Value>1</Value>
    </Item>
    <Node>
      <Item Type="System.String">
        <Property>Name</Property>
        <Value>v2</Value>
      </Item>
      ...
      ...
      <Node>
          ...
          ...
```

How to parse this XML file to read into my TreeNode object? Any clue/help will be helpful.

Comment: LINQ to XML would be the easiest for the parsing of the XML.  You can create the nodes directly from the XML that way.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Walking an XML tree in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291387/walking-an-xml-tree-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     XmlDataDocument xmlReaderDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            FileStream xmlFileStream = new FileStream(F_ECAS_CONFIG.xlmfile_load_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            xmlReaderDoc.Load(xmlFileStream);

            System.Xml.XmlElement root = xmlReaderDoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList messageList = root.GetElementsByTagName("Message");

            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode message in messageList)
            {
                XmlNodeList childnodeList = message.ChildNodes;
                foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode childNode in childnodeList)
                {
                    if (childNode.InnerText.IndexOf("CAS MESSAGE") != -1)
                    {
                    }
                    else if (childNode.InnerText.IndexOf("casTextLine") != -1)
                    {
                        Cl_Ecas_ADE.textline_path.Add(childNode.InnerText); 
                    }
                    else if (childNode.InnerText.IndexOf("casLevel") != -1)
                    {

                        Cl_Ecas_ADE.cas_level_path.Add(childNode.InnerText);
                    }
                    else if (childNode.InnerText.IndexOf("casAckLine") != -1)
                    {
                        Cl_Ecas_ADE.ack_line_path.Add(childNode.InnerText);
                    }

                }
            }
```

its a sample example which i tried in my case it worked..modify as per your code... atleast you will get an idea how to read the tree in XML